# T-SQL Json_modify to append a property to each object

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a stored procedure that accepts a JSON string as input parameter. The input JSON string is like this:

```
[
    {
        "name":"Jhon",
        "surname":"Smith",
        "skills":["C#","VB.NET"]
    },
    {
        "name":"Robert",
        "surname":"Jhonson",
        "skills":["T-SQL","Pascal"]
    }
]
```

How can I add a unique `GUID` property to each principal object automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your example data you already discovered [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-modify-transact-sql) of the documentation that tells you how to insert values with the `json_modify()` function. The examples on that page are written for a single "principal object".

If I interpret this correctly, then your sample has 2 principle objects. Using [another page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-path-expressions-sql-server) of the documentation shows how you can split that sample in rows with the `openjson()` function. You can then apply the `json_modify()` from the first documentation page on each row.

```
declare @var nvarchar(max) =
'[
   {
     "name":"Jhon",
     "surname":"Smith",
     "skills":["C#","VB.NET"]
   },
   {
     "name":"Robert",
     "surname":"Jhonson",
     "skills":["T-SQL","Pascal"]
   }
]';

select row_number() over(order by (select null)) as ObjNumber,
       json_modify(j.value, '$.guid', convert(nvarchar(100), newid())) as ObjValue
from openjson(@var, '$') j
```

The result looks like this:

```
ObjNumber   ObjValue
----------- ----------------------------------------------------
1           {
                "name":"Jhon",
                "surname":"Smith",
                "skills":["C#","VB.NET"]
                ,"guid":"154C5581-588C-41AA-B292-BB6459F8F4DC"}
2           {
                "name":"Robert",
                "surname":"Jhonson",
                "skills":["T-SQL","Pascal"]
                ,"guid":"46ACFDD6-58DE-4DB0-8D7A-9B1CCABFF8D8"}
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=418464b75235f837db19b034e0ee5f61)

To add the rows back together, just add `for json path`. This does however require a field alias (here `MyObjects`) that ends up in the output.

```
select json_modify(j.value, '$.guid', convert(nvarchar(100), newid())) as MyObjects
from openjson(@var, '$') j
for json path;
```

Output:

```
[{"MyObjects":{
     "name":"Jhon",
     "surname":"Smith",
     "skills":["C#","VB.NET"]
   ,"guid":"FCED4D30-B2B0-460B-97FA-EDA820039572"}},{"MyObjects":{
     "name":"Robert",
     "surname":"Jhonson",
     "skills":["T-SQL","Pascal"]
   ,"guid":"9FF02A70-0455-4E5C-8C11-27BB2688929D"}}]
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2ec2db66c62d6322391150ab64b47f8b)

To update the variable use the following code. Bonus: `replace()` removes the previously added field alias.

```
set @var = replace(
             ( select json_modify(j.value, '$.guid', convert(nvarchar(100), newid())) as MyObjects
               from openjson(@var, '$') j
               for json path ),
             '"MyObjects":', '');
```

Final output for `select @var`:

```
[{{
     "name":"Jhon",
     "surname":"Smith",
     "skills":["C#","VB.NET"]
   ,"guid":"66CB37D3-FAEF-4186-94D8-8AC0CF6EB1AC"}},{{
     "name":"Robert",
     "surname":"Jhonson",
     "skills":["T-SQL","Pascal"]
   ,"guid":"564D6904-D981-40AC-BA9C-8B06015ACE50"}}]
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=32b039f574dc00b8559c2befcf0f5ba7)

Comment: Yes, I have already read the documentation but with your example the solution to my problem is now clearer to me. Thanks.

Comment: But if I want add the property into the json string? It possible?

Comment: Certainly, answer updated and here is the [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=32b039f574dc00b8559c2befcf0f5ba7).